# Assigning a random variable based on a probability table/data frame in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, sample

I have a probability data frame like below, called `ptable`:

```
 unique_id color share 
         1   red  0.3  
         1  blue  0.7  
         2   red  0.4  
         3  blue  0.5
```

I'd like to randomly assign a `color` variable based on the `share` variable in the probably table to another data frame `join_table` that looks like below.

```
unique_id count
         1    3  
         2    4
```

I understand sample() but am stuck on how to assign the probability by the shared `unique_id`. My latest attempt was

```
join_table %>% 
group_by(unqiue_id) %>% 
mutate(color= sample(ptable$race[unique_id==ptable$unique_id], 
                     size=n(), 
                     prob=ptable$share[nique_id==ptable$unique_id], 
                     replace=TRUE))
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two typos in the code:

`group_by(unqiue_id)` should be `group_by(unique_id)`
and

`prob=ptable$share[nique_id==ptable$unique_id]` should be  `prob=ptable$share[unique_id==ptable$unique_id]`.

This should work:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
ptable <- tibble::tribble(
  ~unique_id, ~color, ~share,
1,   "red",  0.3,  
1,  "blue",  0.7, 
2,   "red",  0.4,
3,  "blue",  0.5)

join_table <- tibble::tribble(
  ~unique_id, ~count,
  1,    3,  
  2,    4)

join_table %>% 
  group_by(unique_id) %>% 
  mutate(color= sample(ptable$color[unique_id==ptable$unique_id], 
                       size=n(), 
                       prob=ptable$share[unique_id==ptable$unique_id], 
                       replace=TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   unique_id [2]
#>   unique_id count color
#>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1         1     3 blue 
#> 2         2     4 red
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much @DaveArmstrong. The actual `ptable` is 300K rows long and `join_table` has 1.7 million rows. How do I turn a long dataframe into a tribble?

Comment: You don't need to, it should work as is.  A `tribble` was just the easiest way to turn your pasted output into a data frame.